# Accessing local devices in Point of Sale web application

Tags: web-services

I am building a web application, not hosted by the client but on the cloud somewhere, probably azure. It will need the ability to access some local devices such as a receipt printer or cash draw from where they run it. Via a browser this is obviously not possible.

I was thinking of creating a service that they can install locally on their PC that listens to a web service and when it gets a message can perform the tasks such as opening the cash draw.

Is this how people have done similar things in the past? Are there other methods? What technologies do you recommend as I plan on the local service being able to be run on either PC or Mac with minimum fuss. I was considering either Flex or Mono (the app was written in ASP.NET), any other suggestions?

Comment: I am interested to know if you found a elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I will implement something similar to what I have described in the question which is quite similar to what Google have done http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html